# how do I make my code synchronus in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, protractor, synchronous

I want to make my code synchronus, I am used to python but now trying to do
testing things in protractor and some code uses javascript, here things fall apart following is my code :

```
describe('screenshot take', () => { 

    var listLength = urlList.length

      for (let i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
         it('screenshot taken', () => {
          console.log("0")

          TakeScreenshot(  urlList[i],i)  
         console.log("1")

         });
    }
});



function  TakeScreenshot(url,rank){
    console.log("2")

    browser.get(url)
    console.log("3")

    browser.takeScreenshot().then((png) =>{
       console.log("4")
       var stream =  createWriteStream( ImagePath+'.png');  
       stream.write(Buffer.from(png, 'base64'));
       stream.end; 
      console.log("5")


     }); 

}
```

When try look into my console I get the following Output

```
0
2
3
1
4
5
```

But I want it to be

```
    0
    2
    3
    4
    5
    1
```

I have tried using .then() and browser.sleep() but I am not able to gt it I tried reading through async/await but I don't know how to use it. So can someone help me out with this

Comment: Don't. Make your code sequential, but keep it asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi why is it so ?

Comment: Its because  `browser.takeScreenshot()` returns a promise.  Promises take time to resolve, and unless you wait for the promise to resolve, your `console.log("1")` will fire off before the `.then`.

Comment: @johnsmith Remember to mark an answer as the accepted answer  if it worked to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an async function you need to use `await` on other asynchronous functions to make rest of the code wait for their response.

```
describe('screenshot take', async () => { 

    var listLength = urlList.length

      for (let i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
         it('screenshot taken', () => {

          console.log("0")

          await TakeScreenshot(  urlList[i],i)  

          console.log("1")

         });
    }
});



const TakeScreenshot = async (url,rank){
    console.log("2")

    browser.get(url)

    console.log("3")

    const png = await browser.takeScreenshot()

    console.log("4")

    var stream =  createWriteStream( ImagePath+'.png');  
    stream.write(Buffer.from(png, 'base64'));
    stream.end; 

    console.log("5")

}
```

Be aware though that using for loops in async functions is not recommended. You can see more information on why here https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop

Comment: So what do you suggest instead of for loop ? i need all the links from a list of urls

Comment: It should work fine for this example but just keep it in mind for the future when working with async/await as you could run into issues with it. It relates more to performance issue then breaking anything.

Comment: In addition, if we async/await make sure default control flow is turned off by setting `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` property in the config file. In case if control flow is not turned on, the tests will become unreliable. refer https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3037